# MongoDB Shell: find by BinData

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have a document in MongoDB like

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51723a2f2b9b90e9eb190c45"), "d" : BinData(0,"c9f0f895fb98ab9159f51fd0297e236d") }
```

The field "d" is indexed, but how can I find by its value in mongo shell?

e.g.

```
db.test.find( {"d": BinData(0,"c9f0f895fb98ab9159f51fd0297e236d") } )
```

Not working, any idea?

Comment: Try `new BinData` as suggested here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4093

Answer (score 6):

Bindata is the base64 representation of a binary string.Must be instantiated.

```
db.test.find( {"d": new BinData(0,"c9f0f895fb98ab9159f51fd0297e236d") } )
```

Comment: On Mongo `4.0.18`, I had to use `db.test.find( {"_id": new BinData(0,"c9f0f895fb98ab9159f51fd0297e236d") } )`